# Combine two bytes in delphi

Tags: delphi

Provided that I have two bytes variables in Delphi:

```
var 
    b1,b2,result:byte;
begin
    b1:=$05;
    b2:=$04;
    result:=??? // $54
end;
```

How would I then combine the two to produce a byte of value `$54`?

Comment: `result:= (b1 shl 4) or (b2 and $0F);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most trivial way is

```
result := b1 * $10 + b2
```

"Advanced" way:

```
result := b1 shl 4 + b2
```

Comment: you truly better guard the b2 range by `(b2 and $0F);` like another user said in the comment above !

Comment: Sure you are right, but it depends... I don't know where author gets this values, so I assume they are already correct. In most cases they already are, and you do not need to add one more operation.

Comment: well, if one needs so much raw speed that one single extra opcode becomes a problem, he would not write his program in Delphi anyway. So "better safe than sorry" looks more fitting here. Afterall we all use virtual methods and their call (comparing to static methods) is much more expensive than a single `AND AL, 15`. And we all use DLLs/BPLs which also introduce extra burden for every function call, that is less heavy than VMT lookup but still more expensive than single `AND`

Comment: `he would not write his program in Delphi anyway` - yep ))

Comment: @Arioch, "better safe than sorry" doesn't apply here because we have no information on what the desired behavior really is. We've been given *one* example. There are many ways of writing the function so that it returns the desired `$54`, including the trivial `Result := $54`, but it could also be `Result := (b2 + 1) shr 4 + (b1 - 1)`. You cannot argue about which is right without the asker's input. All you can do is mention the possible interpretations and describe how they're different. You've mentioned the possibilities, but haven't given Raw any information with which to judge their merits.

Comment: Well, that's a point. However I was talking with AK, not with Raw, and he seems clearly understanding which situations that guard is intended to protect from.

Comment: Both `b1*16` and `b1 shl 4` compile to `shl reg,4` so your assertion that one is more `advanced` than the other does not make sense.

Comment: So, Jonah, you would like to say that if your particular compiler for your version of Delphi could do it right, that's no need to know the difference between multiplication and bitwise operations? And are you sure that all other compilers/interpreter will work the same way? I do not know how bitwise operations works in Huskell or ES2015... But I still remember that on `8051` controllers family `MUL` operator requires 4 cycles, and `RL` - only one.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to:

```
interface

function combine(a,b: integer): integer; inline;  //allows inlining in other units

implementation

function combine(a,b: cardinal): cardinal; inline;
begin
  Assert((a <= $f));
  Assert((b <= $f));
  Result:= a * 16 + b;
end;
```

Working with byte registers slows down the processor due to [partial register stalls](http://www.ferrousmoon.com/wiki/index.php/Partial_register_stall).
The asserts will get eliminated in release mode.

If performance matters never use anything but integers (or cardinals).

I have no idea why people are talking about VMT's or dll's. It's a simple inline method that does not even generate a call.